# tekton-pipeline ingress route conflicts with kubesphere-console

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have two ingress routes created as below,
kubesphere-console
tekton-pipelines

My manifest files are as like below.
**cat ingress-tekton-dashboard.yaml **

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tekton-dashboard
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingressClassName: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
             name: tekton-dashboard
             port:
               number: 9097
      #host: *
...
```

**cat ../kubesphere/ingress-route-kubesphere.yaml**

```
cat ../kubesphere/ingress-route-kubesphere.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubesphere-console
  annotations:
    kubesphere.io/creator: admin
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: crashandburn.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: ks-console
            port:
              number: 80
---
```

My ingress are as below:

```
k get ing -nkubesphere-system
NAME                 CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
kubesphere-console   nginx   *       20.92.133.79   80      28h
ameya@Azure:~/tekton$ k get ing -ntekton-pipelines
NAME               CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
tekton-dashboard   <none>   *                 80      2m32s
```

My service for tekton dashboard is like below:

```
k get svc -n tekton-pipelines
NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                              AGE
tekton-dashboard              ClusterIP   10.0.202.127   <none>        9097/TCP                             2d3h
tekton-pipelines-controller   ClusterIP   10.0.53.46     <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP,8080/TCP           2d6h
tekton-pipelines-webhook      ClusterIP   10.0.222.121   <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP,443/TCP,8080/TCP   2d6h
```

However, I get the error like below:

```
k apply -f ingress-tekton-dashboard.yaml -ntekton-pipelines
Error from server (BadRequest): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"networking.k8s.io/v1\",\"kind\":\"Ingress\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect\":\"false\",\"ingressClassName\":\"nginx\",\"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect\":\"false\"},\"name\":\"tekton-dashboard\",\"namespace\":\"tekton-pipelines\"},\"spec\":{\"ingressClassName\":\"nginx\",\"rules\":[{\"http\":{\"paths\":[{\"backend\":{\"service\":{\"name\":\"tekton-dashboard\",\"port\":{\"number\":9097}}},\"path\":\"/\",\"pathType\":\"Prefix\"}]}}]}}\n"}},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"nginx"}}
to:
Resource: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses", GroupVersionKind: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Ingress"
Name: "tekton-dashboard", Namespace: "tekton-pipelines"
for: "ingress-tekton-dashboard.yaml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: host "_" and path "/" is already defined in ingress kubesphere-system/kubesphere-console
```

However, I am using two differnt ports for tekton-dashboard and kubesphere-console so wondering why it is complaining.

Comment: If you add `ingressClassName: nginx` to your `tekton-dashboard` ingress, does it work?

Comment: Added more info @blacktide